# docker version number 18.09

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04

See link on explanation of release naming
https://docs.docker.com/install/

My understanding is its using YY.mm. e.g. 18.09.0

So I go to install for ubuntu following steps here
https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-docker-ce-1

where in 3b it gives an example of installing a specific version:

```
docker-ce=18.03.0~ce-0~ubuntu

sudo apt-get install docker-ce=<VERSION>`
```

So I go ahead and do this:

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce=18.09.0~ce-0~ubuntu
```

and get

```
Version '18.09.0~ce-0~ubuntu' for 'docker-ce' was not found
```

So checking cache I have to install

```
5:18.09.0~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
```

What is the 5 about?

Comment: The 5 is the package epoch.  See e.g. <https://readme.phys.ethz.ch/documentation/debian_version_numbers/> for information about Debian/Ubuntu package version numbers and what they mean.

Comment: How come older versions of docker before 18.09 dont have this? Last time I installed it was 18.03.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu

Comment: You don't normally see the epoch.  It was probably there anyway. Your install failed because you didn't have the `-bionic` on the name.

Comment: sudo apt-get install docker-ce=18.09.0~3-0~ubuntu-bionic results in version was not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to specify the 5.
Running the following works

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce=5:18.09.0~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
```

Docker version then shows up as 18.09

Answer (score 1):

It's the epoch. Think of it as a versioning for the version number e.g. if the package decides to change versioning from date-based to semver style, they can begin prefixing version numbers with `1:1.0.1`.

Here's the [official policy manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#version), some examples are [given here](https://readme.phys.ethz.ch/documentation/debian_version_numbers/).